# Creating click to start screen for game

Tags: processing

I am using Processing to create a basketball game. I have managed to create the basketball game but I want to have a click to start home screen. I have made the graphic for the home screen but I am not sure how to integrate it into the game code. Any ideas on how to go about this. Thanks!

I found something on the internet related to this which was...

```
if (started) {
   //all the code for the game
} else {
  // all the code for the start screen
 if (keyDown("enter")) {
   started = true;
 }
}
```

Im not sure if this is leading me in the right direction or how I could necessarily use this.

Answer (score 0):

Use *keyPressed()* outside the *draw()*.

```java
void keyPressed() {
  println(int(key));
  if (key==10) {
    println("ENTER");
  }
}
```

*key* - contains the value of the most recent key on the keyboard that was used (either pressed or released).
What is described in: https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little demo program that may help you. The global variable started controls whether the game has begun or not. The function `keyPressed` sets it to true if you press the ENTER key.

In `draw`, put your game code in the first if-part and your waiting screen in the second.

```
boolean started = false;

void draw() {
  background(0);
  textAlign(CENTER);
  if (started) {
    // your game code here
    text("gameplay", 50, 50);
  } else {
    // your start/launch screen here
    text("waiting...", 50, 50);
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode == ENTER) {
    started = true;
  }
}
```